# How to make appended child appear above all divs just below body tag on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var data = "Mike, Henry, Pete";
data = data.replaceAll(" ", "");
var data_array = data.split(',');
var newArr = data_array.map(x => 'Name: ' + x);
var item = newArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*newArr.length)];

var heading = document.createElement('h1');
  heading.textContent = item;
  document.body.appendChild(heading);
```

The h1 appears below the other divs on the page.(appears at bottom of page)
How do I get it to appear at the top, just below the opening body tag with javascript?

Comment: Achieving the goal, that is... using just javascript

Comment: prepend may be what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You can try using `Node.insertBefore()`.

Try something like this:

```
var heading = document.createElement('h1');
heading.textContent = item;

document.body.insertBefore(heading, document.body.childNodes[0]); // This here...
```

Here, you're basically inserting `heading` element before the first `childNode` of `<body>`. This may throw, you need to make sure `<body>` has children so that `document.body.childNodes` won't be undefined, or you can just use `document.body.firstChild` instead of `document.body.childNodes[0]`.

You can read more about [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Here's an example:

```js
function insertHeading(){
  var heading = document.createElement('h1');
  heading.textContent = "I am the Missing Heading.";
  document.body.insertBefore(heading, document.body.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>I am a paragrapth that belongs to an article. But my heading is missing.</p>
  <p>I am a sister paragraph that belongs to a missing header.</p>

  <button onClick="insertHeading()">Insert heading</button>
</body>
```

---

**Solution 2**

Use `Element.prepend()`:

> The Element.prepend() method inserts a set of Node objects or string objects before the first child of the Element.

In this case `document.body` is your `Element`. You can just append the `heading` like this `document.body.prepend(heading)`.

You can read more about [`.prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend). But this solution lacks browser support. It's not available on `IE` at all.

Comment: "It's not available on IE at all"   

Comment: Lol, But it's true.

Comment: It is indeed true, but IE is end-of-life in less than a month: June 15, 2022 and it's already incapable of dealing with most modern web sites/apps. I have long-since blocked it rather than loading up a million polyfills.